# Syncing MIDI to Click Track

Tags: midi, synthesizer

All my searches only gave me an explanation on how to sync external devices to a Sequencers / DAW (basically by playing a click track and feeding it to your device). I want to do the opposite. I'd like my Korg Volca Beats Sync output to control Ableton Live, so i can access the speed of the setup with the physical dial of the Volca. Is there a plugin or piece of software that can convert click tracks to midi tempo clock?

Comment: If the Korg has MIDI out then you should use that instead of the sync out.

Comment: It does not, only has a midi in.